# Open camera for input type file in Webview not opening Android

Tags: android, webview

I a newbie in android. I am creating a small app to take photo and upload it to server. I am using Webview and html form do that. In browser (chrome) camera is opening. But in webview, camera is not opened when "choose file" is clicked. Anyone know a solution? Below is the code i used....

HTML Code

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Java code used in Android (eclipse)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.inforge.in/thejus/test.html");
}       


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: What version of android are you targeting? It matters

Comment: 4.2.1 Will it not work in other version?

Comment: It only works in android 3+. It should work for you.

Comment: no, its not working. On browser its working, but in webview its working

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/41570241/3518278

Comment: In my case camera permissions were not accepted and we didn't handle the permissions on the webview

Answer (score 7):

try this:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
webview.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);

webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
    // Need to accept permissions to use the camera
    @Override
    public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
        Log.d("onPermissionRequest");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            request.grant(request.getResources());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain "L.d" here?

Comment: it's just Log.d(). logging

Answer (score 1):

You can go through the following open source project to find how others solved this problem. This can help you to improve/fix your code. A direct link to a code snippet of interest: [Getting camera permission in SmartWebView](https://github.com/mgks/Android-SmartWebView/blob/2fe40665884bba87e662ca5144f59de1717204b7/app/src/main/java/mgks/os/webview/MainActivity.java#L577).

[Android Smart WebView. Open Source Project to upload files, get GPS locations and more advanced features](https://github.com/mgks/Android-SmartWebView)

Also, your codes don't have any image capture intent or any file chooser method, you need them to use the camera and also file creation method to write a new image to the device. And, in your Manifest, you need to have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to write new files to the device for upload.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Complete code here.

```
public class ShowWebView extends Activity {

//private Button button;
private WebView webView;
final Activity activity = this;
public Uri imageUri;

private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE   = 2888;
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.show_web_view);

    //Get webview 
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    // Define url that will open in webview 
    String webViewUrl = "http://www.androidexample.com/media/webview/details.html";



    // Javascript inabled on webview  
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Other webview options
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    //webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    //Other webview settings
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); 

    //Load url in webview
    webView.loadUrl(webViewUrl);

    // Define Webview manage classes
    startWebView(); 

} 

private void startWebView() {



    // Create new webview Client to show progress dialog
    // Called When opening a url or click on link
    // You can create external class extends with WebViewClient 
    // Taking WebViewClient as inner class

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {      
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        //If you will not use this method url links are open in new brower not in webview
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {              

            // Check if Url contains ExternalLinks string in url 
            // then open url in new browser
            // else all webview links will open in webview browser
            if(url.contains("google")){ 

                // Could be cleverer and use a regex
                //Open links in new browser
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));

                // Here we can open new activity

                return true;

            } else {

                // Stay within this webview and load url
                view.loadUrl(url); 
                return true;
            }

        }



        //Show loader on url load
        public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {

            // if url contains string androidexample
            // Then show progress  Dialog
            if (progressDialog == null && url.contains("androidexample") 
                    ) {

                // in standard case YourActivity.this
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShowWebView.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }

        // Called when all page resources loaded
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            try{
                // Close progressDialog
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    progressDialog = null;
                }
            }catch(Exception exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }); 


    // You can create external class extends with WebChromeClient 
    // Taking WebViewClient as inner class
    // we will define openFileChooser for select file from camera or sdcard

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType){  

            // Update message
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;

            try{    

                // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard

                File imageStorageDir = new File(
                                       Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                       Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                                       , "AndroidExampleFolder");

                if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                    // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                    imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
                }

                // Create camera captured image file path and name 
                File file = new File(
                                imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                                + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) 
                                + ".jpg");

                mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file); 

                // Camera capture image intent
                final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                                              android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");

                // Create file chooser intent
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");

                // Set camera intent to file chooser 
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                                       , new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });

                // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

              }
             catch(Exception e){
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception:"+e, 
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }

        }

        // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg){
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }

        //openFileChooser for other Android versions
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, 
                                   String acceptType, 
                                   String capture) {

            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
        }



        // The webPage has 2 filechoosers and will send a 
        // console message informing what action to perform, 
        // taking a photo or updating the file

        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {  

            onConsoleMessage(cm.message(), cm.lineNumber(), cm.sourceId());
            return true;
        }

        public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) {
            //Log.d("androidruntime", "Show console messages, Used for debugging: " + message);

        }
    });   // End setWebChromeClient

}



// Return here when file selected from camera or from SDcard

@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  
                                   Intent intent) { 

 if(requestCode==FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)  
 {  

        if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
            return;

        }

       Uri result=null;

       try{
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

                result = null;

            } else {

                // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                result = intent == null ? mCapturedImageURI : intent.getData(); 
            } 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :"+e,
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;

 }

}

// Open previous opened link from history on webview when back button pressed

@Override
// Detect when the back button is pressed
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(webView.canGoBack()) {

        webView.goBack();

    } else {
        // Let the system handle the back button
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: bro, i am new in android. Can you pls edit my code with this. Because when i pasted it, it gives a lot of errors. I tried importing. But still errors. Pls help me

Comment: declare the web view xml as : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
       
   <WebView 
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>       
</LinearLayout>

Comment: have you created xml and then loaded the web view in it as mentioned in the code.

Comment: i am getting same issue but it can't working is there any solution ?

Comment: @MaxGreen Above soln is not working with Android 9.0.pie. Evrything works fine till mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);. but after that nothing is working.  also in logs seen this error "failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your input tag might be mal-formatted.

Try this. It's for the new HTML Media Capture spec

`<input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" capture>`

Or try this older version

`<input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">`

Edit...

Or better yet, use an intent.

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

source: http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskCaptureIntent

Comment: its working in browser. But on webview, its not opening

Comment: Why don't you use a regular intent to open the camera? When the image comes back, you can feed it back into the webview.

Comment: i don't much in java coding. Thats why i choose webview. Can you help me in that regular intent?

Comment: I don't have much experience in java, either. Check the link at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: what i need is take a photo, upload to server, then show a webview

Comment: I understand, but I can't do the project for you. It might help to do some tutorials or take a class before you try to solve a specific problem like this.

Comment: Hi. This solution doesnt work if we ALSO want to show file chooser intent.
In my case, I have 2 options in the HTML, one to open camera directly, other to browse files. I want to open the camera activity directly if user click on 'Camera', otherwise open file chooser intent if the choose 'Browse files'.
How do I handle both kinds?