# How to open camera in android webview?

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I have a web page that is opening in android webview. The requirement is to launch Camera directly on tapping file chooser.

I have written following code for selecting image:

```
<input id="files" type="file" name="images[]" multiple accept="image/*" capture="camera"/>
```

This works fine in chrome browser and opens camera for capturing image. But, when same page is called inside webview, it asks for choose from Camera, Gallery and similar apps.

Comment: You have to implement your own file chooser for the `WebView` and check for the `capture` attribute. I'm sorry but I don't have any source code now to share, I had to implement it in a project some time ago (but I don't have the source code at hand). This is handled by the `WebChromeClient` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this [repo on Github](https://github.com/mgks/Os-FileUp) which is an example of how to to upload and process images/videos in a Webview-based app.

Don't forget to add this in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If you have any more question just ask. I hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested here (FAQ part): https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview
input type and media capture are not supported out of the box. 
Maybe this helps you implementing it on your own:
[Open camera for input type file in Webview not opening Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290940/open-camera-for-input-type-file-in-webview-not-opening-android)

Answer (score 0):

webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

```
        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                request.grant(request.getResources());
            }
        }

    });
```