# Access camera with WebView in Android Studio

Tags: android, webview, camera

I'm creating a QR code reader on a website and now I need to use this site in a Mobile version, so I'm creating a WebView that is opening the site.
But when I get to want to use the QR Code is returning me error when giving permission to use the Android camera.
In any browser the QR Code reader works, on the desktop or on the mobile phone. But when I use the webview, it does not allow the camera.
I need a solution for that.
I've inserted all the permissions and checks I found on the internet but nothing works on any version of Android (I'm using 6.0)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I saw an option to insert a JavaScript to call the camera in WebView but I could not find how it can be done.
Can someone help me

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716217/how-to-open-camera-in-android-webview)

Comment: I try this and not work, tnks for all

Comment: Check the comment on the question, not the answers.