# How to detect camera is off using <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" /> in WebView

Tags: html, input

I use input as following to open camera from smartphone.

```
<input
    onChange=“hoge”
    type=“file”
    accept=“image/*”
    capture=“camera”
/>
```

my website is opened in WebView of some apps and when camera setting is off for those apps and tapping the input above, camera shows up but shows nothing.
I want to tell the use to turn the setting of camera permission to ON, but could not find out how to detect it.

Can someone tell me how to detect camera is off when tapping the input?

Comment: Are you using the webview on android native or any frameworks like react native?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open camera for input type file in Webview not opening Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290940/open-camera-for-input-type-file-in-webview-not-opening-android)

Comment: Note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/input.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.